# Adding entity to Collection removes it from another (Entity Framework)

Tags: entity-framework, collections

guys, I've got very strange problem, that nobody from my company knows.

I have a Collection inside one object, which I created manualy:

```
Cost cost = new Cost 
        {
            ...
        };
cost.Formulas.Add(new Formula()
                {
                    CostID = cost.ID,
                    FieldName = "Distance",
                    Formula1 = "12+2",
                });
```

Next, I got another object with the same type and ID from context:

```
Cost updatingCost = context.Costs.Include("Formulas").FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == cost.ID);
```

And finally I do:

```
updatingCost.Formulas.Add(cost.Formulas.ToList()[0]);
```

And here is magic! After that line cost.Formulas doesn't contains that Formula any more!!

```
cost.Formulas.Count = 0
```

What does this method iCollection.Add() do? Why it removes an object from other collection? It blows my mind, please help to understand it!

Comment: This must have something to do with relationship fix-up. But the strange question is tha, if I understand right, the Formula is removed from the Cost object which is not attached to the Context. Is it right? If the Cost object was attached to the context that would be absolutely normal.

Comment: You're right, the Formula was removed from not attached to context object "cost"! Also, the Formula didn't have any EntityKey and CostID was the same as in "updatingCost"

Answer (score 1):

In fact it is pretty simple. By adding the new formula to another `Cost` object, `updatingCost`, EF changes the foreign key value `CostID` to the value of `updatingCost.ID`.

This is because EF executes *relationship fixup* many times when entites are manipulated in code. This process makes sure that primitive ID values and object references and collection contents match.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but the CostID of object "cost" and object "updatingCost" is the same. So, if EF changed something - it changed EntityKey, not the ID...

Comment: But that's normal if all the objects are attached to the same context, as I told in my comment. However, how is it possible that this happens on an object which isn't attached to the context?

Comment: Oh, I guess I begin to understand... If it would be the same Formula with some ID, the EF conroles that it should be only one Formula attached to Cost and would be strange if the other cost has it too... Cool!

Comment: Yep, the problem is that the object is not in context. For me it was just a temp collection to clone objects, but EF doesn't think so :)

Comment: Maybe even the `cost` object is getting attached to the context when you execute the `updatingCost.Formulas.Add` statement, but as a different object (with a temporary key) than `updatingCost`. You could check the objects in `context.Costs.Local`.